# Which linux distribution and version runs smoothly on intel Pentium processor?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Present OS- Windows10 Home
Processor-Intel Pentium CPU N3710 @1.60GHz
Memory- 4GB
System type- 32bit OS, x64 based processor

Comment: Launch Date Q1'16 means that it is a rather modern CPU. I think most (maybe all) Linux Distros and versions will run well in your computer. I suggest that you try some 64-bit iso files and it should be rather new, with a long time until end of life. Create a USB live drive from each iso file and try it without installing and install the distro that you like best.

Comment: @reviewers: I voted against closing because the opinion is limited to where you draw the line for "smoothly". The different performance requirements are a fact, though.

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer: "most of the large ones".
Did you try one ?

If you are new to Linux and want something easy that still has a bit of a Windows-like feeling then it might be a good idea to try out https://linuxmint.com/ .